# How to find the sum of a set of functions in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

Let's say I have a set of functions

```
MySet == ("A" :> 15 @@ "B" :> 20 @@ "C" :> 32)
```

I want to get X == 15 + 20 + 32, how can I do this in TLA+?
Thank you.

Comment: `MySet` is a function, not a set of functions - you can try this by evaluating `MySet["A"]` and getting `15` back.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you would like to compute - is it `MySet["A"] + MySet["B"] + MySet["C"]` like your example indicates or  would you actually like to create a sum of a set of functions? In the second case you would need to define what the sum of two functions is (there are some natural ways to do this but I'm not sure if that's what you mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXTENDS Functions

Sum == FoldFunction(+, 0, MySet)
```

https://github.com/tlaplus/CommunityModules/blob/master/modules/Functions.tla#L112-L124

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, in the end here is how I did it.

Assuming we have the set of inputs:

```
MyInputs == {"A", "B", "C"}
MyFunctions == ("A" :> 15 @@ "B" :> 20 @@ "C" :> 32)

RECURSIVE Accumulate(_, _, _)
Accumulate(val, inputs, funcs) ==
    IF inputs = {}
    THEN val
    ELSE
        LET x == CHOOSE y \in inputs : TRUE
        IN Accumulate(val + funcs[x], inputs \ {x}, funcs)

sum == Accumulate(0, MyInputs, MyFunctions)
```